# Xcode can't generate previews with Swift Package

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager, swiftui-previews

I'm getting this error because of a Swift package I have added to my project.

```
HumanReadableSwiftError

SettingsError: noExecutablePath(<IDESwiftPackageStaticLibraryProductBuildable:ObjectIdentifier(0x000060001598bf60):'PersonaInquirySDK2'>)
```

This is the package.

https://github.com/persona-id/inquiry-ios-2.git

Is this something I can fix, or help Xcode ignore for previews?

Comment: Same problem here i guess:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707569

Comment: This seems fixed in Xcode 14.1 Beta!